# Align image to the right in anchor

Tags: css, alignment

Can somebody help me to align my image in my `<a>` Tag to the right? The text should have `float: left` and the image `float: right`. The image should also be vertically centered. I don't know, how I can achieve this. Can somebody help me please?

Here is my code http://jsfiddle.net/Vf99v/.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Kind regards, shub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

append

```
#main-nav li a img {
    display: block;
    float: right;

}
​
```

in your CSS and try.

also, maybe you should write the height and width of the image in the HTML, for better browser rendering.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Can you also help me to center the image vertically?